# Dynamic Dropdown Menu Next.js, Strapi

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, next.js, strapi

I'm using Strapi and Next.js to create a Dropdown Menu, but when i hover on a menu button, all dropdown container of the menu show up.
Can anybody show me the way to do it right? Thank you very much!

This is my code:

```
   const Navbar = ({ navbar }) => {
      const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      
      const [mobileMenuIsShown, setMobileMenuIsShown] = useState(false);
    
      const handleClick = () => {setOpen(!open)};
    
      const onMouseEnter = () =>{
        if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
          setOpen(false);
        } else {
          setOpen(true);
        }
      };
    
      const onMouseLeave = () =>{
        if (window.innerWidth < 960){
          setOpen(false);
        } else {
          setOpen(false);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          <nav>
            <div>
                {navbar.topmenu.map((navMenu) => (
                <div 
                onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
                onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
                key={navMenu.id} 
                >
                  <button 
                  onClick={handleClick}>
                    <span class="mr-1">{navMenu.label}</span>
                  </button>
                  {open && 
                  <ul>
                    {navMenu.submenu.map((link) => (
                      <li key={link.id}>
                        <CustomLink link={link}>{link.text}</CustomLink>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                  }
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
      </nav>
</>
```

Comment: You're using the same `open` state for all the nav menus. Try separating each one into a component with their own state instead.

Comment: thanks @juliomalves, i think the same way but i really don't know how to do that. Because it fetch all data from Strapi's back-end, how can i separating each one? Can you show me some example?